# Name for a coordinate system defined on a surface of a [unit] sphere

Tags: geometry, terminology, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

One of the commonly used coordinate systems in 3D is a spherical one. Which would be defined by:

- a radius $r$
- polar and azimuthal angles $\theta$ and $\phi$, where ["mathematicians and physicists would argue about which one is which"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Conventions).

Now, I am working in a coordinate system (?) in 2D which is effectively a set of points on the surface of the sphere ($R\ne 0$), which can be taken as a unit one ($R=1$), since this does not really change anything.

Now, a point is uniquely defined by only $\theta$ and $\phi$.

- Is there a specific name for this particular coordinate system?
- Is there a specific term which would describe such a mapping from 3D to 2D? (say for spheroidal, cylindrical, and other coordinate systems)

Motivation: do not want to invent a bicycle in terms of naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, I don't think there's a very standard terminology. You could call them "latitude longitude coordinates" and no-one would object or be confused. You could perhaps even call them "spherical coordinates" since they are just a restriction to the sphere of the usual spherical coordinates in 3-space.

For your second question, your use of the term "mapping" is confusing to me. Perhaps you simply mean the process of restricting a 3-d coordinate system to a 2-d coordinate system after setting one of the original 3 coordinates equal to a constant? If so, you could call that "restriction of coordinates".

Comment: I think I'd call them "spherical polar coordinates", but latitude-longitude is nice a pretty unambiguous. It'd be safe to say "We'll use latitude-longitude coordinates on the sphere, with latitude ranging from $\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$, and longitude ranging from $0$ to $2\pi$; the earth's axis, in our coordinate system, is the $y$-axis. For simplicity, we'll refer to these as "polar coordinates" The relevant formulas are $\ldots$."